# How can I .send_keys(v.S1) a variable?

Tags: python, selenium

I have only been programing or coding or whatever it is that I am doing for a few days and could use a hand figuring out what I need to research to figure out what I am trying to do. I am working on a project for charity so I dont really want to learn all kinds of things I will probably never use again so I was hoping someone could tell me how to do this or point me in the direction of what I need to learn to make this happen.

So I have created a crawler that goes and types text into a search bar, Eggs for example and then takes me to the eggs results and captures the data, brand, price, count ect.

```
searchBox.send_keys(v.S1)
```

My problem is I can not figure out how to change v.S1 into V.S2 so I can automate going thru many searches without having to copy an paste the code over and over again.

I am working with a main.py to call the functions, a functions.py to store the functions and a variables.py to store the list of variables as S1-S2-S3 ect.

I have been able to to get searchBox.send_keys(v.S1) to work as searchBox.send_keys(X) with a variable X = v.S1
but for the life of me I can not figure out how to add +1 to make X = v.S2 after the function completes the first search.

So far all the information I have needed has been under the same By.CLASS_NAME but I have set those to a variable as well since I may need to change some of those on a per case basis as I go as well.

Well any help or someone pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't change the question based on which you have received well researched answers. Once you receive canonical answers changing the question can make all the existing answers invalid and may not be useful to future readers. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question. StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out. For the time being I have reverted back the question to it's initial state.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add all the S1,S2.... variables in a list or tuple and then iterate using a simple for loop like,

```
# varlist is a list containing all variables
for i in varlist:
    searchBox.send_keys(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass a *character sequence* e.g. *v.S1*, *v.S2*, *v.S3*, etc  you can use the [`range()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/range-to-a-list-in-python/) function and use argument-unpacking operator i.e. * and finally append it to the constant string *`v.S`*

```
elements = [*range(1,6,1)]
elements = ['v.S{0}'.format(element) for element in elements]
print(elements)

# prints -> ['v.S1', 'v.S2', 'v.S3', 'v.S4', 'v.S5']
```

Comment: @Manners What do you mean by _`looking into both suggestions but am not giving up on my original thought process quite yet`_. You wanted to generate _v.S1, v.S2, v.S3, etc_, hence the answer. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have three files, functions, variables and main. main calls functions from functions and functions calls variables from variables. The variables are S1-S15 but will become more as I expand my search. Main calls function def search from functions which .send_keys(v.S1) which calls gallon milk from variables.py S1 then .send_keys(ENTER) waits for html to load then prints(eventually will save to a database) the product name, price ect ect.

Comment: What I need to be able to do is loop this but with .send_keys(v.S1) changed to .send_keys(v.S2) so it can search eggs and repeat the process. The list has 15 searches in it so far so I figured I could do something with S1 like with the integer as a variable like this 'Q = 1
X = f'v.S{Q}'' but I have not figured out how to add +1 to Q after each iteration and .send_keys is just sending v.S1 instead of sending the S1 variable.

Comment: X = v.S1 with .send_keys(X) works fine and calls and sends the variable text but Q = 1 X = f'v.S{Q}' .send_keys(X) sends v.S1 instead of calling v.S1 and sending gallon milk. hope that clears up what I am asking. I could be wrong but it seems like there should be a way to just change a 1 to a 2, 2 to a 3 ect ect to make things work as I imagined. I could be wrong but it seems like this would be such a useful function. I think may be getting closer with return function a class but I have not found an answer yet. I have found other much longer ways but Im trying to keep things short and sweet.

Comment: @Manners If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question. StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: My requirements have not changed. that is the original requirement just explained in a different way. In another way how can I crate a function that loops that iterates a +1 each time it loops. I could fix this in five minutes just by copy/pasting the code 14 more times and changing the the S1-S15 manually but it seems like there has to be a better way than that. My main problem is I dont know what I